# Escape character appears in JSON output

Tags: c#, json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, avro

I'm writing to an Avro file (which is being sent to Snowflake) and one of the fields is a blob of JSON.

This JSON is a collection of elements and values. The shape of this JSON will vay and isn't known until run time so I cannot make a object of the elements/values and use serialize/deserialize to turn it into a JSON string.

The approach I've taken is to use StringBuilder to append the elements and values.

```
StringBuilder newJson = new StringBuilder();
newJson.Append("{");
foreach (Field requestedField in fields)
{
   newJson.Append($"\"{requestedField.Name}\": {FormatValue(requestedField.Value)}");
   if (requestedField != fields.Last())
     newJson.Append(", ");
}
newJson.Append("}");
```

The problem is that when this reached Snowflake is has the escape character backslash in it, and I don't know how. I've tried the obvious

```
newJson.ToString().Replace(@"\", string.Empty);
```

I never thought that would work, and I was right.

EDIT:
Added Field class

```
public class Field { 
  public string Name { get; set; } 
  public string Value { get; set; } 
}
```

I kept the Value type as String as I don't know what is would be until presented with the data from the SQL table.

So, to explain further,

```
List<Field> fields = new List<Field>();
```

Would be a single row in a SQL table, each Field in that List would be a field in that row and the data type of the field isn't know until runtime. Might be bit, varchar, int etc.

If at runtime the user present a table like:

```
ProductName varchar(50)
Price int
OrderCode varchar(10)
Deleted bit
```

Need a JSON output of each row of data in that table like

```
{
"ProductName": "Bucket",
"Price": 199,
"OrderCode": "G1234",
"Deleted": true
},
{
"ProductName": "Spade",
"Price": 299,
"OrderCode": "G5678",
"Deleted": false
}
```

The trick is I don't know the schema of the table until the user gives it to me. So with me (clearly wrong) StringBuilder approach I'm getting

```
{
\"ProductName\": \"Bucket\",
\"Price\": 199,
\"OrderCode\": \"G1234\",
\"Deleted\": true
},
{
\"ProductName\": \"Spade\",
\"Price\": 299,
\"OrderCode\": \"G5678\",
\"Deleted\": false
}
```

If I serialise the Fields object I get:

```
{
"Name": "ProductName",
"Value": "Bucket"
}
```

etc

[Snowflake result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWWQq.png)

Comment: it would be helpful to see more of your code.

Comment: what's the type of your newJson variable ?

Comment: You don't create JSON by concatenating strings. The code you posted concatenates some strings. There's no code that converts the resulting string to JSON, If you try to convert that *string* to JSON, all the double quotes inside your string will be escaped.

Comment: If you want to serialize a list of objects to JSON, `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(fields)`, `JsonSerializer.Serialize(fields)` or whatever the equivalent for your JSON parser, is enough. If `fields` is a `Dictionary<string,T>` or an object you'll get the format you want. On the other hand, any AVRO library will convert values to JSON itself, it doesn't need something to pre-serialize them.

Comment: What AVRO library are you using?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Hi, thanks for your reply
Unfortunately the fields and values are unknown. It is a row from a table in a SQL database and the number of fields, values and their datatypes are completely unknown to the application until the point a user interacts.

So, if could be AccountID =1, AccountName = "Bob Jones". But next it could be "ProductName = "Bucket", Price = 1.99

So I cannot make an object to take the fields and values and serilize, which I agree would be the correct and straight forward approach

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Apache.Avro by Avro

Comment: The fields are always unknown. A JavaScript JSON "object" is actually a dictionary. Serializing is never done using a StringBuilder. All JSON parsers can deal with dictionaries, and a plain old `JsonSerializer.Serialize(someDict);` will work just fine. It's quite likely your AVRO library can *already* handle this scenario though. Especially if it supports `dynamic` objects

Comment: Almost all JSON libraries are capable of working with unknown JSON.  Can you show me your "Field" class and FormatValue() function?

Comment: @DSander Here is the Field class, I kept the Value type as String as I don't know what is would be. I didn't seralise the Field class to convert to JSON as I'd end up with 
{
"Name": "Price",
"Value": "1.99"
}
where is should be
{
"Price": 1.99
}

public class Field
{
        public string Name { get; set; }   
        public string Value { get; set; }
}

Comment: @DSander  I've updated the OP with a better explanation

Comment: How exactly are you initializing `List<Field> fields`? Do you know the database schema during initialization? Are you able to cast the values to their proper types during initialization? Or are you only working with strings and determining type by trying to parse the string as number or checking if a boolean?

Comment: Also, again, please show the FormatValue() function. Is this just determining if it should add quotes or not?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this, but I will give you a solution that more closely matches the approach you already started. If you change your `Field` class so that `Value` is of type `Object` instead of `String` you can just construct a JSON object and then serialize it to a string.

```
public class Field { 
  public string Name { get; set; } 
  public Object Value { get; set; } 
}
```

Assuming your `fields` variable is a `List<Field>` similar to this:

```
 List<Field> fields =  new List<Field>();
 fields.Add(new Field("ProductName", "Bucket"));
 fields.Add(new Field("Price", 199));
 fields.Add(new Field("OrderCode", "G1234"));
 fields.Add(new Field("Deleted", true));
```

You can do something like this with Json.NET (and also other JSON libraries):

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

 JObject json = new JObject();
 foreach (Field requestedField in fields)
 {
      json[requestedField.Name] = JToken.FromObject(requestedField.Value);
 }
 string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(json);
```

The value of output would be a single JSON object:

```
{
  "ProductName":"Bucket",
  "Price":199,
  "OrderCode":"G1234",
  "Deleted":true
}
```

If you need to output a JSON array of these objects as if you had a `List<List<Field>>`:

```
JArray jsonArray = new JArray();
foreach(List<Field> fields in listOfFieldLists)
{
     JObject json = new JObject();
     foreach (Field requestedField in fields)
     {
        json[requestedField.Name] = JToken.FromObject(requestedField.Value);
     }
     jsonArray.Add(json);
}

string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonArray);
```

The output would be:

```
[
   {
        "ProductName": "Bucket",
        "Price": 199,
        "OrderCode": "G1234",
        "Deleted": true
    }, 
    {
        "ProductName": "Spade",
        "Price": 299,
        "OrderCode": "G5678",
        "Deleted": false
    }
]
```

**To Keep Your StringBuilder Approach:**

Thinking about this further, I would need to know how you are initializing the `List<Field>` which you don't quite explain. If you don't have access to the database schema, and you can't cast the values to their proper types when you load the data because you don't know their types, then defining Value as type Object will not work. You would have to determine the type based on the string value. That would explain the `FormatValue()` function you have. It is likely determining whether or not to add double quotes based on if its a number or boolean or not.

In that case, you can still use your StringBuilder output. What you have is what we call "stringified" JSON where all the quotes are escaped so it can be used as variable of a string. In JavaScript you would call JSON.stringify() on an object to get the same result you have. To go back to a real JSON object (which you are asking for) you would call JSON.parse() on your stringified output. To do that in C# you would just parse the stringified JSON from your StringBuilder output using a JSON library like this:

```
JObject realJson = JObject.Parse(newJson.ToString());
```

Then you can convert that JSON object to a string in many different ways without "stringifying" it with escaped quotes like this:

```
string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(realJson));
```

Or:

```
string output = realJson.ToString(Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
```

Comment: Just a note, this assumes the value of `Filed.Name` will always be unique for each object. This will probably be the case for you since you say this is a column name from a database. However, if it is not unique then the values will be overwritten by the last Field in the List with the same Field.Name.

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer. Unfortunately it doesn't solve my problem, but it has allowed me to understand my problem and given me a more elegant way to build the JSON rather then StringBuilder. I'll be asking another question more geared to (what I now believe) is the problem. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you build a proper JSON object, so I think the problem is how you use the output in Snowflake. Do you use PARSE_JSON() function to parse the JSON object?

```
select '{ "Test": "Test" }'::VARIANT as res;

+--------------------------+
|           RES            |
+--------------------------+
| "{ \"Test\": \"Test\" }" |
+--------------------------+

select PARSE_JSON('{ "Test": "Test" }')::VARIANT as res;

+---------------------+
|         RES         |
+---------------------+
| { "Test": "Test"  } |
+---------------------+
```

Comment: Yes, I can run the PARSE_JSON in Snowflake and it's happy with that.

Comment: @CalidXavier. You said "The problem is that when this reached Snowflake is has the escape character backslash in it, and I don't know how." - you need to use PARSE_JSON to parse it to get rid of escaped characters.